# Strange vertical lines on hillshade

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hillshade

I am getting strange vertical lines on my hillshade, anyone experienced anything similar?

I am very new to ArcGIS.

[image]

Comment: Can you say more about the provenance of your hillshade to aid troubleshooting?

Comment: Hi! I used DroneDeploy and a Phantom 3 drone to collect the elevation data, which I then imported to ArcMap and used spatial analyst to create the hillshade.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that these artifacts are a result of Nearest Neighbor sampling, which does well for categorical data, but is not ideal for continuous data. Selecting a resampling method other than Nearest Neighbor, such as Bilinear or Cubic convolution many provide a smoother looking Hillshade.

Answer (score 2):

Long time coming, but I solved this problem by applying the Focal Statistics tool to the DEM before hillshading :-)

Thanks everyone for the help! 
Al