# Smoothing a DEM with visible grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, filter, smoothing, noise

I have a DEM (1x1m) whose hillshade shows like this:

[image]

As you can see, a grid shows up and that could be a problem for hydrological modeling.

Do you know why this happens?

How can I remove this grid from the background of the hillshade?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204218/strange-vertical-lines-on-hillshade/205881#205881

Comment: Get the original model - raster with floating point or use Float if this was imported from ascii file. If no source available, use focal statistics (mean)

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?