# What is the hatch marking of my produced terrain slope raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, slope, analysis

I’ve been piecing together DEM raster data from different sources, in an attempt to create a terrain slope raster. I’m using ArcGIS Pro to merge the DEM’s together and then using the split raster tool to break it apart again, into more manageable areas for further processing. From there, moving into QGIS to run the fill sinks (wang and liu) tool and then GRASS r.slope.aspect tool. But if you look at the image snip, I don’t know where the hatch marking is coming from, what it means, or where to even start when looking for a cleanup solution. I know some of my data is of better quality then the rest, but is there some way to correct for the hatch marking?[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using DEM in a geographic reference, like WGS84 which is in decimal degree units. Try re-projecting the raster data to use a spatial reference in meter units and use the cubic convolution resampling method when reprojecting the raster data and all those distortion lines will be gone.

Comment: Make sure there is no Nearest Neighbour/default resampling anywhere in your process. This is becoming one of the more frequently asked questions on this site, eg [what-is-the-source-of-horizontal-and-vertical-striping-in-usgs-dems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107477/what-is-the-source-of-horizontal-and-vertical-striping-in-usgs-dems). [blocky-srtm-hillshade-in-qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434557/blocky-srtm-hillshade-in-qgis) and [strange-vertical-lines-on-hillshade](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204218/strange-vertical-lines-on-hillshade).